# Adding ManyToMany relationship when clicking a button with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I want to make an app where you can apply to different internships. I have have a database table for students, internships and a joined table student_internship (ManyToMany).

I have a:

**Model Internship.php**

```
public function students()
{
    // Relations, een stage kan meerdere sollicitaties hebben van verschillende studenten
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Student');
}
```

**Model Student.php**

```
public function internships()
{
    // Relations, een student kan meerdere sollicitaties doen op verschillende stages
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Internship');
}
```

and **Model Apply.php**

this is my migration for student_internship

```
 Schema::create('student_internship', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        // dit is voor een ManyToMany
        $table->integer('students_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('internships_id')->unsigned();
    });
```

The button:

```
<h3>Aanbieding</h3>

<p>{{$internship->offer}}</p>

@auth
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Apply</a>

@else
    <a href="/student/login" class="btn btn-success">Login om te solliciteren</a>

@endauth
```

Now what I want to do is I have a button on an internship and when a student clicks on it, the id from te internship and the id from the logged in user (with Auth) should show in the db table with that click. I'm new with Laravel and testing al the things out but now I'm stuck and don't now how to solve this.

Comment: Everything you need to know about a `many-to-many` can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. Basically, you need to send the appropriate information to a Controller, then link the two models via the `attach()` method. Question is a little too broad at the moment, as there's a lot involved in that, but see what you can do and try to narrow down this question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

change the view of that internship in this way:

```php
<h3>Aanbieding</h3>

<p>{{$internship->offer}}</p>

@auth
    <a href="/internship/{{$internship->internship_id /*or the name of the primary key of internship*/ }}" class="btn btn-success">Apply</a>

@else
    <a href="/student/login" class="btn btn-success">Login om te solliciteren</a>

@endauth
```

than inside the web.php create a new route like

```php
Route::get('/internship/{internship}', function(Internship internship)){
   auth()->user()->internships()->attach($internship);
   return "internship applied";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each model, you can also specify the table for the relation, and the id of each model.

**Model Internship.php**

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Student', 'student_internship', 'internships_id', 'students_id');
}
```

**Model Student.php**

```
public function internships()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Internship', 'student_internship', 'students_id', 'internships_id');
}
```

Then in your controller, depending on how you handle the logic, you need the id of the student model and the internship model (This is just an example).

```
public function applyForInternships(Request $request) {
  $studentId = $request->get('student_id');
  $internshipId = $request->get('internship_id');

  // Get the model
  $studentModel = Student::find($studentId);

  // Create the relation
  $studentModel->internships()->attach($internshipId);

  DB::commit();

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `DB::commit();`, unless you're also using `DB::beginTransaction();` before that.